# Tomcat 7 displays status 404 whenever I try to deploy Spring MVC application (from Intellij or by copying war file to webapps)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

Tomcat 7 always displays status 404 resource is not available when I try to deploy (any) Spring MVC application. Moreover it displays the same message when I go to localhost:8080, even though I restarted my Windows. (non-MVC applications are still displed fine).

Here is my web.xml:
{    
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
   <display-name>Spring MVC Hello World</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
          <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>src/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

}

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="hr.altima"/>

</beans>
```

AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

}

And this is just a simple controller:

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home() {
    return "test";
}
```

}

Project directory structure:
[Spring MVC Project http://puu.sh/ueJxx/931682696d.png](http://puu.sh/ueJxx/931682696d.png)

Comment: Share your project directory structure

Comment: @shi Added structure

Comment: Share the sample project to reproduce so that we can verify all the configuration.

Comment: have you checked tomcat log?are you able to connect db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Intellij IDEA, it somehow failed to correctly configure Spring MVC settings and correctly connect all the parts of the project.

After creation of new Spring MVC project, it was working fine.

Also, there was problem with Tomcat. It seems that after a series of unsuccessful attempts which resulted in 404 response, Tomcat started display that same response every time (even for localhost:8080, even after restarting computer...). So I also reinstalled Tomcat and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view resolver configuration to this, I think you are setting it wrong.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Hello World</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It was without `"/WEB-INF/"` because test.jsp file wasn't in WEB-INF. But I moved test.jsp and tried it as you suggested, but still nothing

Comment: your web.xml is also wrong. please use from my updated answer and check.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that my Intellij IDEA didn't correctly configure Spring MVC, so after I created a full new Spring MVC project it started working correctly